# It's there a big difference between application request routing 2.5 vs application request routing 2.0

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, iis-7.5, arr

We currently use ARR 2.0 and some new feature exist in ARR 2.5! It's there a big performance difference between the two version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you use it.  If you leverage the disk caching, there are supposed to be nice performance improvements.  I haven't tested personally to know how much though.  Here's the [release post for 2.5](http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/archive/2011/03/28/microsoft-application-request-routing-arr-version-2-5-has-been-released.aspx).